# Getting attribute values in VBA

Tags: ms-access, dom, vba, getelementsbytagname

I need to make a VBA file that will read a webpage and return the value of the SRC attribute of the IMG tag. I wasn't able to make the last step work. Can you guys help me?

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="image.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

===Edit===
I managed to return the attribute object. Now I need to return its value

```
Option Compare Database

Sub AcessaPagina()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim test As String
    Dim obj As Object

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com.br"
    MsgBox ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img").Item(0).Attributes("src")
    ie.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

That's what I have at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no method called "getElementByTagName" -- it's called **getElementsByTagName** (note the **s** because it is a collection)

The Document Object returns a collection of all the img tags in the source. So you can iterate it like this:

```
Sub AcessaPagina()
    Dim ie As Object ' InternetExplorer
    Dim images As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim image As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate "http://www.google.com.br"
    Set images = GetAllImages(ie)

    For Each image In images
      Debug.Print image.getAttribute("src")
    Next image

End Sub

Function GetAllImages(ie As Object) As Object
  Set GetAllImages = ie.document.images
End Function
```