# Need a vb version of DOM getElementByAttribute

Tags: vb.net, excel, dom

I know that there are tons of versions in JavaScript out there but I need this as a vb version for use in Scripting in Exel 2010? Has anyone done this translation?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213850/getting-attribute-values-in-vba

Comment: I think he needs the MSHTML library in VBA, I added an example

Comment: ARe you talking about DHTML DOM, or XML DOM? If it's XML DOM, then he would need to add the MSXML2 library and use those methods in VBA

Answer (score 0):

If your query is for XML DOM methods, , then in the VB Editor in Tools > References add a reference to Microsoft.MSXML2

goto 1) below!

If your query is for DHTML DOM methods, then in the VB Editor in Tools > References add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml

1) Then you can access the DOM using all the methods that you see in the Object Browser (keystroke f2 in the VB Editor, then select MSHTML in the drop down to select DHMTML DOM Library.

an example using MSXML would be:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
y=x.childNodes[0]
msgbox y.nodeValue
```

an example (using MSHTML) would be :

```
Sub testDoc()
Dim xDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim sURL As String
Dim oElement As MSHTML.HTMLBaseElement
Set xDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

With xDoc
    .Open (sURL)
    Set oElement = .getElementById(idName)
    MsgBox oElement.ID
End With

End Sub
```

I hope that gets you started in the right direction.

BTW, 
Philip